# Changing date format in Pentaho using javascripting

Tags: pentaho, kettle, e4x

I have an input excel sheet which has a field "fail_date". I want to change the format to `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss`. I am doing this in javascript shown below.

```
var temp = fail_date.getDate();
str2date(temp,"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

But I get the below error when i run

> 2015/05/07 17:48:01 - Modified Java Script Value 2 2 2.0 - ERROR
>   (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by
>   buildguy) : Could not apply the given format dd.MM.yyyy on the string
>   for Thu Jan 01 11:05:50 IST 1970 : Format.parseObject(String) failed
>   (script#5)

script#5  points to `str2date(temp,"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");` . Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: `getDate()` in javascript `Date` object returns the date of month `[1-31]`. Looks like you are passing an invalid date to be converted. You will have to show the value of `temp` and body of the function `str2date` for further help.

Comment: The value present in Input excel is "1970/01/01 11:05:50.312" [data type is Date]      

In pentaho, this value is read in "temp" and value is "Thu Jan 01 11:05:50 IST 1970" . 

In pentaho, str2date is an inbuilt function. USAGE : str2date("01.12.2006 23:23:01","dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable temp is setted as date type object, but when you apply the str2date function, this function expects to be temp as string.

So this is how your code should be:

```
var temp = fail_date.getDate();
temp = date2str(temp,"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

remember now temp is a string type

Comment: Also, now, the variable temp is set as string. 

var temp = fail_date.getString();                         

temp = str2date(temp,"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");             



But I get the below error


Could not apply the given format dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss on the string for 2015/03/02 04:00:31.000 : Format.parseObject(String)